# Draw physics body with two circle shape cocos2d v3?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, draw, physics

I want to draw Red onze Physics Body in cocos2d v3. A shape with 2 circle and perforation. Is it impossible and how to do that by code ? Thanks

http://greenhornbold.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/RED-CIRCLE-2.jpg

Comment: use the linked image as a sprite maybe?

Comment: perhaps you could fake a perforation in the circular physics body that you attach to the sprite by skipping the collision method when another body collides with that part of the circle.

Comment: @abhineetprasad: the problem is: I need a stick through the hole. The stick keep the red circle shape will not fall.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D thanks but it make a circle Physic body.

Comment: do you want it to be a "donut" like shape? This requires that you build the torus shape from convex polygons and the body uses multiple shapes. PhysicsEditor can build these shapes for you from a provided torus image.

Comment: if thats the case , I would second @LearnCocos2D's suggestion of using multiple shapes to build the torus shape as faking a hole would involve a number of work-arounds.

Comment: yep, thannks for you guy much.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're asking about?

```
projectile.physicsBody = [CCPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:projectile.contentSize.width/2.0f andCenter:projectile.anchorPointInPoints];
```